# How to select specific data according to a button pressed

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a combination of html and php that makes my markup as follows:

```
<div class="row">
            <?php foreach($requests as $request) : ?>
            <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <p class="telegram_id">
                    <?php echo $request['telegram_id'].' restaurants id'; ?>
                </p>
                <p class="restaurant_name">

                </p>
                <p class="places">
                    <?php echo $request['places_count'].' places are left now'; ?>
                </p>
                <p class="discount">
                    <?php echo $request['discount_count'].' % is the discount U get in this restaurant booking with us'; ?>
                </p>
                <p class="timestamp">
                    <?php echo 'Updated at '.$request['created_at']; ?>
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Wanna order</button>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

At the end there is a button and there is a markup for the modal as well. How do I pass data froward to the modal according to which button was pressed. I mean, let's say there are 10 div's of class item with different contents and 10 different buttons. How do I get the p tags that are inside the div where the button was pressed?

Comment: which data you wan to pass?

Comment: @brk that's the contents of p tags. I need kind of say look for the p tags that are inside of the div of class item inside which the button was pressed

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function with `<div>` id when user click on the `<div>` and this id should be dynamic that generate with your loop index. for example, I show you 2 `div` with id `item1` and `item2` , here 1 and 2 is your loop index.

```js
function getPContent(item){

  alert($("#"+item+" p.telegram_id").text()+ $("#"+item+" p.places").text()+$("#"+item+" p.discount").text()+$("#"+item+" p.timestamp").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item1">
    <p class="telegram_id">
        telegram_id1
    </p>
    <p class="restaurant_name">
    </p>
    <p class="places">
        places1
    </p>
    <p class="discount">
        discount1
    </p>
    <p class="timestamp">
        timestamp1
    </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="getPContent('item1')">Wanna order</button>
</div>
<div id="item2">
    <p class="telegram_id">
        telegram_id2
    </p>
    <p class="restaurant_name">
    </p>
    <p class="places">
        places2
    </p>
    <p class="discount">
        discount2
    </p>
    <p class="timestamp">
        timestamp2
    </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="getPContent('item2')">Wanna order</button>
</div>
```

Comment: One love for the answer. I cannot vote for it, but You made my day! Huge thanks!

Comment: you are welcome @Alex, if my answer help you and is the right one then please accept it, thanks.